# Determine which checkbox is been clicked

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I've chosen Ember.js for one my project and this is the first time I'm fiddling with this framework. Currently, I'm trying to get my mind around the framework and I'm stuck at one particular problem.

I've scenario where the user will be given a list of checkboxes to mark the give item and I've to trigger an ajax call after determining which checkbox has been checked. List of checkboxes is been fetched on demand from the server and they may vary per item.

My question is how do I determine which checkbox is been clicked by the user, so that I will be able to make an ajax call?

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/miferefivu/1/

Comment: Any code which can help us to understand more about the issue ??

Comment: @RahulB I've attached a jsbin link in the post.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do using a bit of jQuery is if your checkboxes can share either a common prefix on their id or a common class. You can add the event like so for each case:

```
$(".checkboxclass").click(function(e) {     
    console.log($(this).prop("id"));
});

$("input[id^='checkbox-']").click(function(e) {          
    console.log($(this).prop("id"));
});
```

You can then either by checking the checkbox's value or id determine which checkbox has been ticked

Comment: This is very jqueryish approach. I'm looking for some idiomatic Ember approach. Thanks anyways.